# form_for doesn't invoke the right function in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not able to call the right method from my controller when using `form_for`.

I have the following view:

`<%= form_for [:admin, @build_config], :url => admin_user_test_creds_path, html: {class: "rf-form rf-col--6"} do |f| -%>`

My controller has a method called as `test_creds` which I want to be called from this form.

My `routes.rb` has the following route:

```
post "/user", to: "user#test_creds", as: "user_test_creds"
```

However, it doesn't invoke the `test_creds` function, instead calls `create` method in controller. What am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: show me `rake routes | grep test_creds`

Comment: `admin_user_test_creds POST   /admin/user(.:format) admin/user#test_creds`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[:admin, @build_config]` from parameters of `form_for`